# How to get the last value in Node in XML

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the last text inside node which is the ID 104543.

```
<id>tag:website.com:feed/web/main/104543</id>
```

The output should be 104543.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .NET 3.5 or higher, then you could use the XElement class in System.Xml.Linq.
You could retrieve the tag element content in the following way:

```
string str = @"<id>tag:website.com:feed/web/main/104543</id>";
XElement element = XElement.Parse(str);
var content = element.Descendants("id").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Now, parsing the content depends on how this is structured: if the code you want to extract will always be placed after the last "/" character, then you could do the following:

```
string code = content.Split(new[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last();
```

Comment: I get an error, when I put the breakpoint. var content = element.Descendants("id").FirstOrDefault().Value; <-- Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.